# Convert very small number to larger positive value in Python

Tags: python, math, floating-point

I have numbers including very small numbers like [1e-30, 1e-22, 1e-18, 1, 10].
I want to convert them larger value than 0 and current numbers like [1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 10.0, 11.0]. (the value can be anything but keep them in order)
I try this first, but [sys.float_info.epsilon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) make them zero.

```py
>>> math.log(1 + 1e-30)
0.0
>>> math.log(1 + 1e-18)
0.0
```

You can use any way to make them greater value.

Comment: Instead of `math.log(1 + x)`, have you tried `math.log(1 + x * 1e30)` or something similar?

Comment: but I want to keep them in order after conversion. 1e-30 < 1e-18 < 1e-22 -> x < y < z

Comment: It is not clear how you want to transform values. Something like  `-100/math.log(x)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to keep them in order". Have you tried: `l1 = [1e-30, 1e-18, 1e-22]; m = min(l1); l2 = [math.log(1 + x * m) for x in l1]`

Comment: @MBo any way is ok if it's not too small.

Comment: @Stef I misunderstood, I think your solution works, thanks

Comment: To address the purely numerical issue: did you try using [`math.log1p(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log1p) in place of `math.log(1+x)`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson this is what I am looking for, but it does not work well when the value is very small
math.log1p(1e-23) is 1e-23, which is not expected

Comment: @harry: It's certainly the result _I_ expect: mathematically, `log(1+x)` is close to `x` for small `x` (the Taylor expansion of `log(1+x)` about zero is `x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4 + ...`). If it's not the result that you *want*, then you should be looking for a different mathematical function. Can you  be more explicit about the properties you need?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I updated the question. basically you can use any way to make the given value greater. small numbers are difficult to handle, so I want to make them bigger.

Comment: _Multiply_ each value by `(1.0 + 1e-15)`.  (e.g. 1.0 + sys.float_info.epsilon)

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this transformation:

```
import math
a=[1e-100, 1e-20, 1e-3]
for x in a:
    print(-100/math.log(x))

0.4342944819032518
2.171472409516259
14.476482730108394
```